# Record video from camcorder in C#

Tags: c#, camera, webcam, video-capture

I need to be able to record video from an external camera in a C# application.

Unfortunately a webcam is pretty much out of the question as the application will record outside and during the evening/night. That is why I was thinking of a camcorder since it also has manual control over exposure and focus, lower noise and better sensor.

So far I would use the AV/S-Video output from the camcorder and send the signal to a USB capture card (the computer is a laptop so no PCI-E cards).

1. How would I be able to access the video stream from the C# application, now that it comes from the capture card ?
2. Does my proposed system seem feasible (achievable, good video quality, good fps)? Does anybody have another working solution?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is a bit off topic and hard to answer. Any comments on feasability will be subjective, will you be able to pick the right answer? What you suggest is obviously feasabile at the general level but, as ever, the devil is in the detail. What API does the undefined USB capture device have?

Comment: A bit off what topic? I am interested in a working solution where I can record video from an external camcorder. I also described the "system" as I see it right now but I am definitely open to other suggestions.

Comment: I also edited my question to explain what I mean by feasible

Comment: As it stands, I think you want to identify what hardware capture device/mechanism to choose. Once you know that, you can ask questions about how to interface with your chosen device. However you are not at the coding stage so cannot ask a coding question. Hence, the question is off topic.

Comment: The nature of my request indeed requires some hardware decisions but it also involves coding ones (e.g. what libraries to choose, services, etc)

Comment: Due to the time constraints, in the end I chose to use a camera instead of a camcorder. Maybe on the next project :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used in the end was Microsoft Expression Encoder.

Answer (score 1):

This [Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15537/Camera-Vision-video-surveillance-on-C) could be of a good starting point.

The Author mentions :

> The main goal of the application was to make it flexible and
>   extensible. The application itself can communicate with any video
>   source – it may be an IP video camera or a server, it may be a local
>   camera attached to USB, it may be an MMS stream from a remote server,
>   or it may be any other video source. And more of it, the application
>   can work with all these video sources simultaneously, displaying them
>   all on a single screen.

Comment: @Jodrell I haven't tested the application. but see my updated answer

Comment: did that, deleted erroneous comment.

Comment: Thank you AbZy. I see that it focuses on IP cameras but I will look into that MMS stream.